# Channel configuration policy in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am following the below beginners guide to set up a block chain.
[Hyperledger Fabric Channel Policy Tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/policies.html#configuration-and-policies)

Can someone please advise me how to specify these policies in configtx.yaml file? 
Or is it should be specified somewhere else ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

To specify the endorsement policy for a channel, you include it on the `peer channel deploy` transaction using the `-P` switch. From the example in the [Endorsement Policy guide](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html#specifying-endorsement-policies-for-a-chaincode), a channel with a policy to request a signature from Org1 and Org2 would be as follows:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C testchainid -n mycc -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"
```

The syntax of the language is:

```
EXPR(E[, E...])
```

where `EXPR` is either `AND` or `OR`, representing the two boolean expressions and `E` is either a principal (with the syntax described above) or another nested call to `EXPR`.

Comment: Hi Christo, 
If you see the sample configuration file, policies are not mentioned in it. 
configtx.yaml contains only Profiles then orderer & application configuration not channel policy configuration.

Comment: oh, sorry, too quick on the trigger. See amended answer.